# Write an xkcd feed bot

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, internet

The new xkcd feed bot room gave me an idea for a simple challenge.

Your code will have to monitor the xkcd website and output all the new comics to the user.

## Specs

- When first run it should just sit around waiting.
- Then, when randall posts a new comic, within a minute, it should display the new comic in any of our usual standards for images (display, save, etc.)
- If the comic is interactive and not a simple image, then print out the string `"interactive comic"`.
- This does not include the comics which are an image inside a link, those still have to be displayed normally.
- After displaying the image, it should go back to waiting around for the next update.
- Your program cannot access any sites except http://xkcd.com

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: Link to the feed bot room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44753/xkcd

Comment: "*If the comic is interactive and not a simple image*" then how do we know? At present this seems underspecified.

Comment: A decent strategy would be to only check during the two to three hours around midnight eastern US time on M/W/F, but that would miss those comics he occasionally posts on other days (like April Fools and those week-long series he did in the past).

Comment: @PeterTaylor If it's a single image, there will be a permalink to the image on the page. If not, there won't be. You could also test to see if the main content pane contains an `<img>` tag.

Comment: @PeterTaylor there will be an image tag in the correct position, not an iframe or whatever else he uses

Comment: Are we allowed to use RSS feed libraries such as `feedparser`?

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+ & Default Browser, <s>215</s> 217 bytes

```
$l=date;for(){if(($x=([xml](iwr xkcd.com/rss.xml)).rss.channel.item[0]).pubdate-ge$l){if(($y=$x.description)-match'img src'){saps ($y-replace'<img src="'-replace'" .*')}else{echo "interactive comic"}}$l=date}
```

***WARNING:*** Running this as-is will likely make Randall very mad at you, due to the high frequency of calls to the RSS feed ... **so, y'know, don't do that.** (See below for an alternate version that can be used in a one-off manner)

Sets the `$l`ast time we displayed a comic to the result of `Get-Date`. Then, enter an infinite `for` loop.

Each iteration, we `iwr` (alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`) the RSS feed for the site. That's parsed as `[xml]` (yes, PowerShell can cast as XML), and the `.rss.channel.item[0]` thereof (i.e., the newest) is stored in `$x`. If the `.pubDate` is `-ge$l` (i.e., newer than the last comic we showed), we have a new comic to display.

So, we first check the `.description` field (saved in `$y`), to see if it matches `img src`. If so, we parse out the img from `$y`, and feed that to `saps` (alias for `Start-Process`). Since it's a URI, this relies on Windows' default behavior for "executing" a URI, that is, it opens the default browser to that location. (*If this is too cheaty, let me know and we can `iwr` down the actual image and save it.*)

Otherwise, we `echo` out that we've got an `interactive comic`.

In either case, we update our `$l` date to "now" since we just displayed a comic.

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to Matt for reminding me that `http://` can be implied*

---

#### "Safe" version that executes just once and displays the latest comic

```
$l=(date).AddDays(-3);if(($x=([xml](iwr http://xkcd.com/rss.xml)).rss.channel.item[0]).pubdate-ge$l){if(($y=$x.description)-match'img src'){saps ($y-replace'<img src="'-replace'" .*')}else{echo "interactive comic"}}
```

You can run this one safely to see how the logic works. It'll only execute once and only display the latest comic.

Comment: Why did you use `echo` here? `echo "interactive comic"`? Or am I not seeing the nested parentheses and you are capturing data somewhere else? Also `iwr xkcd.com/rss.xml` seems to work

Comment: @Matt When doing testing locally, I was getting inconsistent results without an explicit `echo` -- sometimes the output wouldn't update until the next time the XML updated, and then *two* "interactive comic"s would be output simultaneously. -- Thanks for the golf on `http://`, I keep forgetting that can be implied.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you could probably DDoS xkcd with this.

Comment: @Mathime I don't know if it'd reach DDoS levels, but it would definitely be a Bad Thing™, hence my disclaimer.